# call a class directly from visualforce email template

Tags: visualforce, email-template, class

Is it possible to call an apex class directly from visual force email template to execute some tasks? Like for example how you call a controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need

[Using Custom Controllers within Visualforce Email Templates](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_email_templates_with_apex.htm)

[using custom controllers in visualforce email templates Blog by CloudForce](http://www.cloudforce4u.com/2013/10/using-custom-controllers-in-visualforce.html)